# In R how to pass a column as parameter to strsplit?

Tags: r, tidyverse

What is the proper way to pass a column as parameter to a str_split function and have it recognized as a column?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lazyeval)
df = data.frame("x"=c("apple/pear","pear/banana/kiwi","orange/pear"))
function (col) {
  mtcars %>%  
  select(col) %>% 
  transform(col = interp(strsplit(~v, "/"), v=as.name(col)) )
}
```

currently this is returning error 'Error in strsplit(~v, "-") : non-character argument'

Comment: The base `strsplit` function you are using requires a character vector input. From `?strsplit`, *" Other inputs, including a factor, will give an error."* All the `mtcars` columns are numeric, not character. Hence the error, "non-character argument". If you switch to `stringr::str_split`, as in your title, you might have success. Otherwise, convert to `character` before splitting.

Comment: The earlier example has not been well thought. I added a dummy data frame instead to illustrate the issue

Comment: How do you run this code outside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` options instead of mixing `base R` with tidyverse.  `separate_rows` from `tidyr` splits the column and reshape it to 'long' format.  Inside the function, we can make use of the curly-curly operator (`{{}}`) that evaluates unquoted argument to the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
f1 <- function(data, col) {
           data %>%
                separate_rows({{col}}, sep="/")
   }

f1(df, x)
```

Comment: amazing. is {{}} a notation to pass in parameters and recognize it as a column?

Comment: @santoku Yes, it is a compact way which does the combination of `!! enquo(col)`